# Windows 8.1 XAML Flyout under a MenuFlyoutItem

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

Is there a way to have a `Flyout` popping out after clicking a `MenuFlyoutItem` of a popped `MenuFlyout`.

It kinda looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Status">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem.Flyout>
                                <Flyout>
                                    <TextBox Width="200" />
                                    <Button />
                                </Flyout>
                            </MenuFlyoutItem.Flyout>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Yet the sample doesn't display the `Flyout` under `<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Status">` when clicked. How will I correct this one?